# Php function with ifelse, foreach and in_array

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

Aim. Multiple times (in multiple places) need to check value of array key and based on the value inside `foreach` need to echo currency code.

Have array (as example), named `$data_pvn_1_ii_each_invoice_debit`

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [VatCodeCountryCode] => IE [VatCode] =>123456 ) 
[1] => Array ( [VatCodeCountryCode] => GB [VatCode] =>958725 ) 
)
```

Here define variable which includes abbreviations of countries, where currency is euro.

```
$country_codes_with_euro_currency = array( 'AT', 'BE', 'CY', 'DE', 'EE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'IE', 'IT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'PT', 'SI', 'SK' );
```

Then multiple times (in multiple places) need to check value of `[VatCodeCountryCode]` and based on country code need to echo currency

At first trying to get `[VatCodeCountryCode]`.

```
foreach($data_pvn_1_ii_each_invoice_debit as $i => $result){
$trim_result_vat_country_code = trim($result[VatCodeCountryCode]);
}
```

Then function (part of function)

```
function myTest($trim_result_vat_country_code) {

if ( in_array($trim_result_vat_country_code), $country_codes_with_euro_currency) ) {
return $currency_code = 'EUR'; 
}

elseif ( $trim_result_vat_country_code == 'GB' ) {
return $currency_code = 'GBP';
}   

}
```

And then need to echo currency code (also only part of code)

```
<?php foreach($data_pvn_1_ii_each_invoice_debit as $i => $result){?>
<tr><td>
<?php echo myTest($trim_result_vat_country_code); ?>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>content of other td</td></tr>
<?php }?>
```

First problem: code does not work with `( in_array($trim_result_vat_country_code), $country_codes_with_euro_currency) )`

Second problem: `echo myTest($trim_result_vat_country_code);` returns only last result. For array key `VatCodeCountryCode` there are values `IE` and `GB`. So need to echo currencies `EUR` and `GBP`. But echo only `GBP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Problem :**

```
if( in_array($trim_result_vat_country_code), $country_codes_with_euro_currency))
```

should be

```
if( in_array($trim_result_vat_country_code, $country_codes_with_euro_currency))
```

In `in_array` function second parameter should be an `array`.

**Second Problem :**

```
foreach($data_pvn_1_ii_each_invoice_debit as $i => $result){
  $trim_result_vat_country_code = trim($result[VatCodeCountryCode]);
}
```

Your above code holds only the last record.That is why `myTest` function returns only last records.

**Solution :**

```
<?php foreach($data_pvn_1_ii_each_invoice_debit as $i => $result){?>
<tr><td>
<?php echo myTest($result['VatCodeCountryCode']); ?>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>content of other td</td></tr>
<?php }?>
```

Modifiy your `myTest` function

```
function myTest($trim_result_vat_country_code) {
    global $country_codes_with_euro_currency;
    if ( in_array($trim_result_vat_country_code, $country_codes_with_euro_currency) ) {
        return $currency_code = 'EUR';
    } elseif ( $trim_result_vat_country_code == 'GB' ) {
        return $currency_code = 'GBP';
    }
}
```